# Implement 2D rotation using multi touch

Tags: android, scroll, rotation, zooming

In this code are implemented:

- zooming (with double tap and touble touch event)
- scrolling
- coordinate transformation from pixel to UTM

Using the class `Matrix`, are the proportions. In this way the coordinates are correct.

I would add the rotation image, but I don't know how to do it.
Could someone help me?

This is my image activity:

```
public class MapActivity extends Activity {

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    TouchImageView img = new TouchImageView(this);
    img.setImageResource(R.drawable.planimetria);
    img.setMaxZoom(10f);
    setContentView(img);
}
```

This is the java file with the class:

http://pastebin.com/afukpgyZ

Thank you so much for the help.